# Xaml 2009 support in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, silverlight

When are WPF and Silverlight going to support Xaml 2009 in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the xaml 2009 compiler is going to be relesed. Next VS by deafault.

Since there is no compiler performance of xaml 2009 app is lower, VS does not provide intellisense, some markups are marked as errors et cettera. I'd you use it in only one situation though. I have dynamic layout which is loading some elements form data base to adapt layout to specific situation.

Comment: So it sounds like 2012 at the earliest, based on the other 2-3 year cycle of releasing Visual Studio.

Comment: @JoshVarga not VS2012 either. I guess we'll have to wait longer.